# Check if a string appears in any of the keys of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to check if a string is **in** one of the keys of a dictionary.

```
if message in a_dict: # this will only work if message is exactly one of the keys
    #do stuff
```

I want the condition to return `True` even if `message` is only *part* of one of `a_dict`'s keys.

How would I do that? Is there a way to add a regex `.*` in the string? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Then you need to iterate over the keys and check each one. This does mean losing much of the efficiency of a dictionary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `any`:

```
elif any(message in key for key in a_dict):
    do_something()
```

If you need also the key which contains the message:

```
else:
    key = next((message in key for key in a_dict), None)
    if key is not None:
        do_something(key)
```

Comment: Nice, is there a way to pas `key` to `do_something`?

Comment: Do you want only one key or all keys, that contain the message?

Comment: Hmm, would there be a problem with using both examples such as: `elif ...: key = next...` BC when I tried this, the next function returned false/true seemingly randomly.

Comment: The second example will not work for me.  I tried this to see what the problem was:  `key = list(message in key for key in a_dict)` this returned a list of true/false values, instead of key.

Comment: Ok i used this `list(key for key in a_dict if message in key)` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do what you want with Python's `in` operator. It's best to do the check by hand - iterate over all the keys and see if any of them contains your `message`.